# Assign Events Using the HTML DOM JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am learning JS,and I have an example which I don't understand.
When we call functions like this it works:

```
       <button onclick="displayDate()">Try it</button>
```

This also works:

```
   <script>
        document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;

        function displayDate() {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
        }
  </script>
```

But when I change this `displayDate` to `displayDate()` it shows me the date when page is loaded,so onclick doesn't work. My question is: why does JS DOM work like this? What is really happening? Do we not call a function like this: `function();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
something = functionName();
```

it means to call the function immediately, and then put the value that it returns into `something`.

When you write:

```
something = functioName;
```

it means to put a reference to the function into `something`, but not call it. This allows the function to be called later, using that reference. When `something` is `someElement.onclick`, this happens when the user clicks on the element.